# libGDX iOS application crashes after calling creat()

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, robovm

I created a game app using libGDX and its running successfully on my desktop, android emulator and on my android device, however, when trying to launch it as an iOS simulator app I get the following errors:

> [WARN] android.System: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace
>   but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding
>   resource leaks. [WARN] android.System: java.lang.Throwable: Explicit
>   termination method 'close' not called     at
>   dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java)    at
>   java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java)    at
>   java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java)    at
>   java.lang.PathClassLoader.init(PathClassLoader.java)  at
>   java.lang.PathClassLoader.findResource(PathClassLoader.java)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java)   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java)   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas$TextureAtlasData.(TextureAtlas.java)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.(TextureAtlas.java)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.(TextureAtlas.java)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.(TextureAtlas.java)
>     at
>   com.appsandsmiles.MammiMammiGameHelpers.AssetLoader.load(AssetLoader.java)
>     at com.appsandsmiles.MammiMammi.MammiMammiGame.create(MammiMammiGame.java)  at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics.draw(IOSGraphics.java)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics$1.draw(IOSGraphics.java)
>     at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIView.$cb$drawRect$(UIView.java)     at
>   org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)  at
>   org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)     at
>   com.appsandsmiles.MammiMammi.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java)

and:

> com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found:
>   data/spritesheet.atlas (Internal)     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java)   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas$TextureAtlasData.(TextureAtlas.java)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.(TextureAtlas.java)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.(TextureAtlas.java)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.(TextureAtlas.java)
>     at
>   com.appsandsmiles.MammiMammiGameHelpers.AssetLoader.load(AssetLoader.java)
>     at com.appsandsmiles.MammiMammi.MammiMammiGame.create(MammiMammiGame.java)  at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics.draw(IOSGraphics.java)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics$1.draw(IOSGraphics.java)
>     at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIView.$cb$drawRect$(UIView.java)     at
>   org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)  at
>   org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)     at
>   com.appsandsmiles.MammiMammi.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java)

I tried to create an hallo word project to check and see if it's running on the iOS simulator and it did so I guess the problem is somewhere in the code, but as I mentioned in the beginning the app does work on android device and on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the second log block, it seems that you either don't have the "data/spritesheet.atlas" in the correct location or that your ios project doesn't fetch it's resources from the android projects "Assets" folder.

If the "Data" folder mentioned in your log refers to the ios projects "Data" folder you should probably move your graphics to the "Data/Assets" folder in the android project.

Comment: All of my assets files (including spritesheet.atlas) are located on Data/Assets in my Android project.

Comment: Show some code for when you are loading your assets then... You might refer to the wrong directory

Comment: But how can it be?! the app working fine on Android and Desktop

Comment: Are you doing anything at all in your IOSLauncher class?

Answer (score 0):

After checking the code again, I noticed that the problem was in my robovm.xml file.

The problem was fixed after changing it from:

../GameName-android/assets/data

to

../GameName-android/assets